# Gain time intervals in Django

Tags: django, time, intervals

I created a model in Django that records user visits to the product. I want to check if the user's previous visit, for example, was an hour ago, another visit is recorded in the model. How can I get this time interval ??

Answer (score 0):

Middlewares can help you to solve your problem.
You can write a middleware which gets the user IP and checks if the user's previous visit was an hour ago or not, then depend on the condition you can create a new model instance or update an exists one.
It is easy to use a datetime field to check the interval between now and the last visited time.

Comment: My only problem is getting time
How should I get it ??